# rails 3.2 optimize the load time for index page

Tags: caching, methods, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2, varnish

I have an index page that is displaying 8 charts and each chart have a select option with 3 options (12h, 24h, 48h). Each option is a DB call so 24 calls to the DB every time the index page is refreshed/called.  The loading is very slow as it has to do 24 queries to the DB each time. What will be the best way to optimize the page load so that it is not slow?
I thought of caching? varnish?
Or is there a way to have the functions in another controller instead of the index method in the home controller, so that they are not called every time the index page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Caching won't help if your data changes continuously. I think you can use [Futures and promises](https://github.com/bhuga/promising-future)

gem.

Or alternatively you can defer loading of every charts, load every chart one by one so you will query database individually for every chart.